# Append multiple excel sheets and create a identifier column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, append

I am in a situation where I would like append multiple excel sheets coming from a single workbook on top of each other and build an identifier column.
The identifier column will be built via extracting a word(within brackets of a column) from the column header, essentially creating a new column and storing that extracted information in it. Here is an example:
My excel workbook has two sheets , "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" and their header looks like this:

Sheet1:

```
a       b         c         d(Connect) 
1       2         3         4
11      22        33        44
```

Sheet2:

```
a       b         c         d(Connect2)
5       6         7         8
```

What I want is to append these two sheets together in a way that the resultant dataframe should like following:

```
identifier    a      b     c     d
Connect1      1      2     3     4
Connect1      11    22    33    44
Connect2      5      6     7     8
```

The idea is that the identifier should be placed corresponding to each and every row when we are appending the sheets on top of each other.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After importing each sheet add the identifier column to each df and concatenate them:

```py
sheet1['identifier'] = "Connect1"
sheet2['identifier'] = "Connect2"
new = pd.concat([sheet1, sheet2], axis=0)
```